# Which TextFieldDelegate method should be called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

In my application , I want to show one popover view, whenever I am clicking in textfield. 
Which text field delegate method should I call?

Comment: thanx for quick reply.. I tried that one.. but its getting called only once... My requirement is..if i am clicking again in textfield..popover should come again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write your functionality in

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{        
    // became first responder
}
```

Comment: thanx for quick reply.. I tried this one also.. but its getting called only once... My requirement is..if i am clicking again in textfield..popover should come again

Comment: ok it's work but text field must complete it's -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField; method first. can you post your popover controller creations

Answer (score 0):

Use on the UITextFieldDelegate protocol......

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  NSLog(@"Editing Should Editing");  // SAVE PROCEDURE
```

}

Comment: thanx for quick reply.. I tried that one.. but its getting called only once... My requirement is..if i am clicking again in textfield..popover should come again

Comment: use on the  -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;